# Extra space in layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I was following this  tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/. I copied this layout:

recycler_items:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
            </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUrl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:textColorLink="@color/link" />

        <info.androidhive.listviewfeed.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason I have extra white space in the right side, like 1/5 of the screen. When I preview it in the app is not there, but on the phone it is. I know that the problem is this layout because if I replace everything with just the image, it will fill the whole width. Here is a picture with the problem : http://6pix.net/images/89726012394405680403.jpg .Where does the extra space come from ?

This is my recycler which takes the items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"


        />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is how I inflate the recyclerItems:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_items, null);
```

Comment: If you are using FAB button you have to use CoordinatorLayout. To solve this issue put your LinearLayout inside a CoordinatorLayout which is in android design support library. Use this url for more info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html

Comment: This layout is for a `recyclerView`, which is in a fragment, which is in a layout that uses CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: Check the code where you are declaring the FAB. There might be some problem there.

Comment: It is not. I even deleted the fab button and the space was still there. I'm sure the space comes from this layout. As I said if I delete everything from this layout except the FeedImageView(or any other element) they will have full width.

Comment: There is something wrong, but I can't figure out which part

Comment: @BogdanDaniel show us your layout with the FAB button. The problem is your child views not coordinate with others that's why you have to use CoordinatorLayout. Anyway show us your full layout.xml.

Comment: @TdSoft I posted everything related to this layout. The activity layout ->recyclerView_layout->fragmentLayout-recyclerItems

Comment: But I still think the problem is related only to the first layout. As I said if those where the problem I should see only 4/5 no matter what is in the first layout.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel I checked your layouts. There was no issue in your layouts.

Comment: @TdSoft Thank you.  I've been looking at this problem for the past hour and still haven t found a solution

Comment: @Bogdan Can you make some changes in one of the setting available in Developer Options - Show Layout bounds. It is helpful from there to see how that space is occupied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem. I found the solution in modifying the way I inflate the recyclerItems layout.

Change from

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_items, null);
```

to

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_items, viewGroup, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To put 2 XML tags/images on top of one another, use a RelativeLayout. I'm not 100% sure which of your XML Tags refer to what on the screen, but play around with Relative Layout. So for example, maybe try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height=" fill_parent "
    tools:context="name.company.newapp.Recycler.RecyclerView">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/content_recycler_view" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, but as I said in the comments above I'm 100 percent sure that the listItemsLayout is the problem. I will edit everything now because I know that the other layouts are not the problem